# While statement keeps on looping even though it should not be technically possible

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I am writing a Selenium Python script that is supposed to scrape all hyperlinks from all the pages and switches in between them using the "next" button which it clicks on. This successfully scrapes all the links but when it gets to the last page where the "next" button element should no longer exist it keeps on looping on that last page and keeps on writing the scraped data over and over again to the CSV file forever.

To my understanding with my setup of the while and try/except statement this should not be technically possible. Been messing with the code for hours now and lost my hair because of it but I still didn't manage to fix it.

This is the website that I am trying to scrape the information from :
https://www.sreality.cz/adresar

As you can see there are red company titles and there is the "next" arrow button at the bottom. This is my code that is supposed to scrape all the links :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException, TimeoutException
from platform import system
from os import getcwd, getlogin
import csv

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

with open('links.csv', 'w+', newline='') as write:
    driver.get("https://www.sreality.cz/adresar")
    writer = csv.writer(write)
    page_spawn = 0
    while page_spawn == 0:
        try:
            links = wait.until(ec.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h2.title > a")))
            #print(len(links))
            for link in links:
                print(link.get_attribute("href"))
                writer.writerow([link.get_attribute("href")])
            wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.btn-paging-pn.icof.icon-arr-right.paging-next"))).click()
        except TimeoutException:
            page_spawn = 1
            break
```

Comment: Your `except` will only fire if you hit a `TimeoutException`. Are you sure that the code throws that exception, and not something else, like a `NoSuchElementException `?

Comment: It should throw a TimeoutException to my understanding as it's been like that for other "suddenly missing" elements in the past. However even if I do something like :

except Exception as e:
page_spawn = 1
break

the result is still the same unfortunately

Comment: Another thing to check: You say that ""next" button element should no longer exist", but have you checked the page source to ensure that the element actually doesn't exist, and not that it exists but isn't visible or isn't clickable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That arrow button element still exists on [the last page](https://www.sreality.cz/adresar?strana=152) but is disabled:

```
>> window.location
Location https://www.sreality.cz/adresar?strana=152

>> document.querySelector("a.btn-paging-pn.icof.icon-arr-right.paging-next")
<a class="btn-paging-pn icof icon-…ht paging-next disabled" ng-href="" ng-class="{disabled: !pagingData.nextUrl}">
```

Invoking the `click()` method on the element just does nothing.

Given that the disabled element has a `disabled` class value, adding `:not(.disabled)` to the end of that selector will prevent it from matching the disabled element:

```
>> window.location
Location https://www.sreality.cz/adresar?strana=152

>> document.querySelector("a.btn-paging-pn.icof.icon-arr-right.paging-next:not(.disabled)")
null
```

while still matching against the non-disabled element:

```
>> window.location
Location https://www.sreality.cz/adresar?strana=151

>> document.querySelector("a.btn-paging-pn.icof.icon-arr-right.paging-next:not(.disabled)")
<a class="btn-paging-pn icof icon-arr-right paging-next" ng-href="/adresar?strana=152" ng-class="{disabled: !pagingData.nextUrl}" href="/adresar?strana=152">
```

Comment: This actually makes total sense! I knew that the element was disabled but didn't realise that the selector would still pick it up after that. Anyways using :not is the perfect solution I think. Thanks for letting me know of this!

Answer (score 0):

You are not changing the value of `page_spawn` in the try block that might be the reason for looping n times.